# Custom Property not being bind after re-mapping in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a view model which is working fine for the first time. Here is the model i have.

```
function MessageTViewModel() {
    var self = this

    self.SelectedUser           =   ko.observable()
    self.ProfileId          =   ko.observable()

    self.ExistingCommunication  =   ko.observableArray([])
    self.NewCommunication       =   ko.observableArray([])
    self.DeclinedCommunication  =   ko.observableArray([])
    self.Messages               =   ko.observableArray([])

    self.LoadData   =   function(){
        self.InitializeData()
    }

    self.InitializeData =   function(){
        var url =   'Messaging/Index'
        var type    =   'GET'
        ajax(url , null , self.OnInitializeDataComplete, type )             
    }
    self.OnInitializeDataComplete   =   function(data){
        var existingCommunication   =   getCommunication(conversation,'Existing')
        self.ExistingCommunication(existingCommunication)
        self.SetSelectedUser(existingCommunication[0])
    }
    self.SetSelectedUser = function(data){
        self.SelectedUser(data.ProfileId)
        self.InitializeUserData()
    }       

    self.InitializeUserData =   function(){
        var data    =   {ids : self.SelectedUser()}
        var url     =   'Search/GetProfile'
        var type    =   'GET'
        ajax(url , data , self.OnInitializeUserDataComplete, type )             
    }
    self.OnInitializeUserDataComplete   =   function(data){
        self.GetConversation()
    }

    self.GetConversation = function(){
        var data = {/// blah blah ///}
        var url =   'MessagingApi/Conversation'
        var type    =   'GET'
        ajax(url , data , self.OnGetConversationComplete, type )                
    }
    self.OnGetConversationComplete = function(data){
        var messages    =   ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Messages)
        self.Messages(messages())
        self.AddClass()
    }   
    self.AddClass = function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Messages(),function(item){
            item.LikedClass = ko.computed(function(){
                var status = item.TargetUserAction()
                return (status=='Liked') ? 'mlike_a' : 'mlike'
            }) 
            item.DislikedClass = ko.computed(function(){
                var status = item.TargetUserAction()
                return (status=='Disliked') ? 'mdlike_a' : 'mdlike'
            })                      
            item.FlagClass = ko.computed(function(){
                var status = item.TargetUserAction()
                return (status=='Flagged') ? 'flag_a' : 'flag'
            }) 
        })
    }               

    self.ChangeUserChat = function(data){
        self.SetSelectedUser(data)
    }

    self.LoadData()
}

$('document').ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new MessageTViewModel())
})
```

I have removed the extra code from this.

And here is the view genertaed.

```
<article class="prfl_box">
    <a data-bind="event:{click:$root.ChangeUserChat.bind($data)}">
        <img class="right_navm" alt="">
    </a>
    <h3 data-bind="text:WithUsername">talha.akber23</h3>
</article>
<article class="prfl_box">
    <a data-bind="event:{click:$root.ChangeUserChat.bind($data)}">
        <img class="right_navm" alt="">
    </a>
    <h3 data-bind="text:WithUsername">raheelshan123</h3>
</article>
```

As you can see on anchor click i am calling ChangeUserChat. So that the to change the user information i am displaying in other section. Here is the sequence of call.

On Load Data

```
self.SetSelectedUser(existingCommunication[0])
self.InitializeUserData()
self.GetConversation()
self.AddClass()
```

And On call to ChangeUserChat

```
self.ChangeUserChat = function(data){
    self.SetSelectedUser(data)
}
self.InitializeUserData()
self.GetConversation()
self.AddClass()
```

Now it is calling AddClass method which works fine on Load but always give error on ChangeUserChat. It always says `LikedClass is not defined` . I assume it is not calling AddClass method or somehow avoiding it. How can i resolve this problem. I have checked adding console.log after AddClass and console is displaying the result.

EDITS:

I have two sections in my page. like this

[image]

Now. By default the first item is assigned to `self.SetSelectedUser(existingCommunication[0])` which then fills all right side of my page with all the infor needed and adding 3 more properties in each message. See `self.Messages()`. Next here is my binding

```
<ul>
    <li id="chat-time-ago"></li>
    <li>
        <img src="../images/spacer.gif" data-bind="attr:{class:LikedClass()}">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="../images/spacer.gif" data-bind="attr:{class:DislikedClass()}">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="../images/spacer.gif" data-bind="attr:{class:FlagClass()}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine for the first time but when i click on item 2 and call `self.ChangeUserChat` it says `Likes Class is not defined`.

Comment: In which line do you get this error `LikedClass is not defined`? How are using using `LikedClass` in your view?

Comment: Try to rewrite your AddClass to `self.AddClass = function(messages){  ` and use the paramter messages instead of `self.Messages()` and change the order in the `OnGetConversationComplete` to `var messages    =   ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Messages)
        self.AddClass(messages())
        self.Messages(messages())`

Comment: @nemesv thats working exactly according to your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @nemesv can you post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you add your computed properties after you have assigned the items in your `Messages` array. So KO starts to render the UI which references your `LikedClass` but it is not able to find it.

One solution is to move the `AddClass` logic before setting the `Messages`

```
self.OnGetConversationComplete = function(data){
   var messages = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Messages)
   self.AddClass(messages())
   self.Messages(messages())
}
```

Of course to make this work you need to change your `AddClass` method to don't directly work with `self.Messages()`:

```
self.AddClass = function(messages){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(messages, function(item){
            //... add your computeds
    })
}
```